# What does this mean Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()

Tags: android, react-native

Note: Huge  Android studio NOOB.

It is my first time on working on apps, I am installing  android studio in ubuntu 20.4, I am working on a react native project, I am following this tutorial

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup  ( click on React Native CLI Quickstart)

at the ending as given in the documentation, I use these two commands in separate terminals

**npx react-native start at terminal 1 **

** npx react-native run-android at terminal 2**

this is the error I get this error.

followed through google for errors but none of them seems to be working

[image: Screenshot]